# What to do if GPS is off on a Android App with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-edittext

WHAT I WANT IS A GUI TO COME UP IF THE GPS IS OFFLINE SO USER CAN INPUT CURRENT ADDRESS.

I am building a Android App in Eclipse with Google Maps.  One of my Activities brings up a mapview when opened.  What I would like to do is if the GPS is not on instead of loading the map I would like the activity to show a EditText Text view where the user can enter a address for their current location, then the map view would show up after entering this address.  I have all of the Logic to get the GPS Boolean to show if the GPS is on but what I would really need is the Activity.java and layout xml logic that would show either of these GUI items based on the GPS Being on.  So if GPS is on the mapview will show, if the GPS is not on the activity would show a area to enter the address and a button, and once the button is clicked this logic will bring up the location on the mapview that the user entered.

Activity.java file

```
 @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
      public class MapViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
            static LatLng currentLatLng;
            LatLng currentLocation;
            private GoogleMap map;
            boolean firstPass = true;
            double currentLat;
            double currentlong;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    showCurrentLocationOnMap(); 
    try {
        showSheltersAndFuelStops();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
//This will change when SQL connection string is implemented.
private void showSheltersAndFuelStops() throws IOException {
    List<McDonalds> mcdList = new ArrayList<McDonalds>();
    List<Subway> subwayList = new ArrayList<Subway>();
    String subwayRoswell1 = "1307 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203";
    String subwayRoswell2 = "1701 W Second St, Roswell, NM, 88201";
    String subwayLC1 = "2001 E Lohman, Las Cruces, NM, 88001";
    String subwayLC2 = "2821 N Telshor, Las Cruces, NM 88011";
    String mcdonaldsRoswell1 = "720 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88201";
    String mcdonaldsRoswell2 = "1804 S Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203";
    String mcdonaldsLC1 = "4810 Mesa Grande, Las Cruces, NM, 88012";
    String mcdonaldsLC2 = "571 Walton Blvd, Las Cruces, NM, 88001";

    Subway subway = new Subway(" 1307 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203", 1.58, 8.0);
    subwayList.add(subway);
    Subway subway1 = new Subway(" 1701 W Second St, Roswell, NM, 88201", 2.47, 12.0);
    subwayList.add(subway1);
    Subway subsLC = new Subway(" 2001 E Lohman, Las Cruces, NM, 88001", 147.99, 185.0);
    subwayList.add(subsLC);
    Subway subsLC1 = new Subway(" 2821 N Telshor Drive, Las Cruces, NM, 88011", 147.12, 200.0);
    subwayList.add(subsLC1);

    //This will be replaced by a Read Only Stored procedure that gets the List of Shelters
    McDonalds mcdonalds = new McDonalds(" 720 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88201", 1.08, 8.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonalds);
    McDonalds mcdonalds1 = new McDonalds(" 1804 S Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203", 2.9, 12.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonalds1);
    McDonalds mcdonaldslc = new McDonalds(" 4810 Mesa Grande, Las Cruces, NM, 88012", 143.2, 185.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonaldslc);
    McDonalds mcdonaldslc1 = new McDonalds(" 571 Walton Blvd, Las Cruces, NM, 88001", 147.62, 200.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonaldslc1);

    showFuelStops(subwayRoswell1);
    showFuelStops(subwayRoswell2);
    showFuelStops(subwayLC1);
    showFuelStops(subwayLC2);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsRoswell1);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsRoswell2);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsLC1);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsLC2);
}


private void showFuelStops(String location) throws IOException{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
    List<Address> addresses;

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fillingstation);
        currentLat= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        currentlong= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng subLoc = new LatLng(currentLat, currentlong);
        Marker fuelMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(subLoc).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("Subway, " + location));

    }       
}

private void showShelters(String location) throws IOException{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
    List<Address> addresses;

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.shelter);
        double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng subLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(subLoc).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("McDonalds, " + location));

    }       
}

private void showCurrentLocationOnMap(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    SupportMapFragment mf= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map = mf.getMap();
    //map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    LocationListener ll = new Mylocationlistener();
    boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPS){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, ll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_view, menu);
    return true;
}
/**
 *Mylocationlistener class will give the current GPS location 
 *with the help of Location Listener interface 
 */
private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    private boolean zoomed = false;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            // ---Get current location latitude, longitude---

            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Marker currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            if (!zoomed) {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
                zoomed = true;
            }
            if (!firstPass){
                currentLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            firstPass = false;
            Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this,"Latitude = "+
                    location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
      }

  }
```

activity_map.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <fragment
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Based on the isGPS Boolean that I set in the Activity.java file I could use this as a Boolean switch.  Is there a way to change the gui as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is! Just toggle visibility of the Map/Edit view based on the GPS status. For example you could have the map invisible by default like so:

```
<fragment
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:visibility="gone" />
<EditText ...put stuff here... />
```

Then from your code, check if GPS is turned on then:

```
if (gpsIsOn)
{
    mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: What about the rest of the onCreate Method?

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me what will happen if the user enters an address? it should be displayed on the map right? but for this you would need to get the corresponding `LatLng` point. for this you would need access to `GPS service` or at least to Network service to get the coordinates.

Comment: Well, yes if the user enters a address then hits the Ok button it will be displayed on the map, I do have logic that will convert the address to a lat and long but I am asking about the GUI.